# Same bottom margin in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a document with hundreds of pages (~300 pages) written in MS Word. I observed somehow in some of the pages, the bottom of each pages are not the same between each other. See figure below for example:

[image]

Somehow, MS Word continue the sentence in Page 4 to Page 5 even though as we can see the sentence can be fit to Page 4. This makes such not a nice layout (i.e. not equal "height" of the document).

I already use page margin for the whole document, but it didn't help as well. This "symptom" happened not only at this particular page, but in some other pages as well.

Any solutions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.

"Bottom margin" set in Word is the minimum value.
Everything which would cross that, or would be below is placed automatically to the next page.

E.g. if you use different fonts, font sizes, line spacing in your text, that means they take different vertical space, so you likely to end up with different residual space at the bottom of the page. This is the reason of small differences.

Also paragraph settings "page break before", "keep with next" and "keep lines together" may push text to the next page even if it would fit before, causing several lines to be empty on the bottom of the page.